# Meteor insert into collection appears to work, but remains empty

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I'm doing a simple insert into a meteor collection that appears work, but leaves the collection empty.

The collection is defined properly on the server:

```
Meteor.publish("comments", function () {
return Comments.find();
});
```

Subscribed to properly in the client.js:

```
Meteor.subscribe("commments");
```

And set up properly on the model.js:

```
Comments = new Meteor.Collection("comments");
```

The insert code is as follows:

```
Meteor.methods({ 
    addComment: function (options) {
    check(options.post_id, String);
    check(options.comment, NonEmptyString);

    if (! this.userId)
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must be logged in to comment.");
    if (options.comment.length > 1000) 
        throw new Meteor.Error(413, "Comment is too long");
    var post = Posts.findOne(options.post_id);
    if (! post)
        throw new Meteor.Error(404, "No such post");
 // add new comment
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log('Comment: ' + options.comment);
    console.log('Post: ' + options.post_id);
    console.log('UserId: ' + this.userId);
    var saved = Comments.insert({
        owner: this.userId,
        post_id: options.post_id,
        timestamp: timestamp,   
        text: options.comment});
    console.log('Saved: ' + saved);
   }
});
```

Once the insert is called, the console prints out the following:

```
Comment:  Something 
Post: xRjqaBBEMa6qjGnDm 
UserId: SCz9e6zrpcQrKXYWX 
Saved: FCxww9GsrDsjFQAGF 
> Comments.find().count()
0
```

I have inserts into several other collections that work just fine (Posts being one of them as you can see the post ID in the code).  In the docs ist said that if the insert errors out it will print to the console, but as you can see it appears to be working, yet is actually empty.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I did find that the data is being put into the database, but for some reason is not showing up.  I'm not sure why the data is not being published properly since there are no filters on the find().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but there's a few things to check here.

• First, this:

```
Meteor.publish("comments", function () {
    return Comments.find();
});
```

directs the server to publish the Collection, but doesn't actually establish the collection server side.

You should have `Comments = new Meteor.Collection("comments");` available on both the client and the server. I tend to put in a file called model.js like the [examples](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/parties/model.js) tend to do.

• Second possibility, you don't have a subscribe function shown above, such as `Meteor.subscribe("comments");` If you don't have a subscribe function, your client isn't going to know about it, even though it does exist in the collection.

You can test this theory by typing `meteor mongo` in the shell (with your Meteor app running), and `db.comments.find()` to see if your comments are actually in the database but not subscribed to.

Comment: I checked my code and I forgot to note that I do have the Meteor.subscribe in my model.js.  I have the Comments = new Meteor.Collection("comments"); in the main page, but I also have the same for Post and Section collections and they work as expected.
I did check and they are in the database.  Any other idea why they might not be showing?

Comment: `Meteor.subscribe(...)` should be in your client code, not shared... Perhaps update the code in your question? It should be very easy to locate the bug if I could see where it is :)

Comment: My mistake (I still need my morning coffee).  The Meteor.subscribe() is on the client, not the model.  
The Comments = new Meteor.Collection("comments"); is in the model.js file.

Comment: `Meteor.subscribe("commments");`  <-- extra 'm' in the code or just in the question?

Comment: Amazingly I had the exact same problem in the exact same place in the book!

Answer (score 0):

Verify you do not have an error in your client code.  With Meteor.call, if you do not initialize a variable you can have an error condition that will block reactive updating in your templates but continue to write fine to your console just before hand.

I've made that mistake which I talk about here:
http://doctormehmet.blogspot.com/2013/07/revoltdc-hackathon-20130622-iteration-3.html

Specifically I had something like

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
   somevar: function({
              if (some_session_var_set_by_a_call.party){
              //do something
              } 
}
```

Now the somevar function gets called on render, before the Meteor.call returns.  Therefore the variable some_session_var_set_by_a_call isn't set yet.  The whole thing stops client side on the undefined error.

Comment: As you can see, I check for errors and log all the variables before inserting.  Nothing errors in the console either.  Is there something else I can do to check?  Also, I did check the db directly per @emgee suggestion and I'm showing that the comments are being posted.  Now it seems that the issues is that client code is not accessing the collection properly.  Ideas?

Comment: Erick I can't see that, because I can't see your Meteor.call function, your render functions,helper functions or your template that you serve to the client.  Since you have no errors, why don't you try a print (console.log) inside a callback within the Meteor.call function and see what happens.  You also need to connect some sort of reactive element (either a session.get or a cursor) in the template to update it when the asynchronous function returns at a later point.  The asynchronous function must modify that reactive variable to create the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I misspelled 'comments' as 'commments'.

Comment: Did that break the code then on the client? Was I right?  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: It didn't error out.  It just tried to return everything from the database in the 'commments' collection, but it didn't exist.  Appreciate you taking the time to review this. :)